# Как внести результаты запроса к базе данных в XML-файл?

Tags: xml, java, hibernate, jsp

Создаю web-сервис. Использую netbeans; hibernate для работы с БД, а именно:

- Создал внутреннюю БД в netbeans.
- Создал java-классы -представление таблиц БД с set'ами и  get'ами . Разметка-аннотациями.
- Создал hibernate.cfg.xml и HibernateUtil.java.

А вот теперь, как сделать запросы к БД и результаты внести в формируемый XML-файл? 
Именно в XML, т.к. сервис будет доступен и с Андроида, а я не хочу, чтобы с Андроида был доступ к файлам Web-сервиса. Т.е. Запрос->формирование XML с ответами->последующий парсинг.

**Update:** В общем интересует:

1. Пример простого SQL запроса(допустим
       вывести всех пользователей)
2. В каком виде приходит ответ
3. Создание XML-файла внутри программы.(можно в рабочий пакет)

Comment: Мне кажется, ответ содержится в самом вопросе, - дальше разбирайтесь с хибернейтом и веб-сервисами.

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не получается в запросах или в записи xml?

Comment: а литературу сможешь подсказать какую-нить?

Comment: Я ниче не понял... Надо помочь с HBML? Или надо пояснить генерировать XML? Если генерировать XML - то куда его писать? В БД или куда? Вообще в чем вопрос? Наверное я туплю...

Comment: 1. Пример простого SQl запроса(допустим вывести всех пользователей)
2. В каком виде приходит ответ
3. Создание XML-файла внутри программы.(можно в рабочий пакет)

Answer (score 1):

1. Примеры смотрите например [здесь](http://0agr.ru/blog/2011/04/14/9/)
2. Hibernate выдаст вам ответ в виде Java объектов (в виде бинов согласно
       вашему маппингу)
3. Формирование XML можно устроить несколькими способами:

   - Тупо генерировать текстовыми строчками (работает железобетонно, но некрасиво)
   - Использовать нечто вроде XStream - легкий способ (пример [здесь](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)) или [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) - тяжелый способ

Comment: Почему JAXB - тяжело? (Сам только начал разбираться в теме и кроме JAXB ничего не видел...)